# Convert HTML table data into transposed 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, html-table, html-parsing, transpose

I need to scrape the data from an HTML table and orientate the columnar data as rows of a 2d array.

My code does not display the correct structure.

HTML Table:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>header</td>
        <td>header</td>
    <td>header</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>test</td>
<td>test</td>
<td>test</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP CODE:

```
$DOM = new \DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML($valdat["table"]);
                
$Header = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('tr')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('td');
$Detail = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('td');
      
//#Get header name of the table
foreach($Header as $NodeHeader) 
{
    $aDataTableHeaderHTML[] = trim($NodeHeader->textContent);
}
//print_r($aDataTableHeaderHTML); die();

//#Get row data/detail table without header name as key
$i = 0;
$j = 0;

foreach($Detail as $sNodeDetail) 
{
    $aDataTableDetailHTML[$j][] = trim($sNodeDetail->textContent);
    $i = $i + 1;
    $j = $i % count($aDataTableHeaderHTML) == 0 ? $j + 1 : $j;
}
//print_r($aDataTableDetailHTML); die();

//#Get row data/detail table with header name as key and outer array index as row number
for($j = 0; $j < count($aDataTableHeaderHTML); $j++)
{
    for($i = 1; $i < count($aDataTableDetailHTML); $i++)
    {

        $aTempData[][$aDataTableHeaderHTML[$j]][] = $aDataTableDetailHTML[$i][$j];
    }
}

$aDataTableDetailHTML = $aTempData;
echo json_encode($aDataTableDetailHTML);
```

My result:

```
[{"header":["content"]},{"header":["test"]},{"header":["content"]},{"header":["test"]},{"header":["content"]},{"header":["test"]}]
```

We need such a result:

```
[
   ["header","content","test"],
   ["header","content","test"],
   ["header","content","test"]
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed a lot of the code to (hopefully) simplify it.  This works in two stages, the first is to extract the `<tr>` elements and build up an array of all of the `<td>` elements in each row - storing the results into `$rows`.

Secondly is to tie up the data vertically by looping across the first row and then using `array_column()` to extract the corresponding data from all of the rows...

```
$trList = $DOM->getElementsByTagName("tr");
$rows = [];
foreach ( $trList as $tr )  {
    $row = [];
    foreach ( $tr->getElementsByTagName("td") as $td )  {
        $row[] = trim($td->textContent);
    }
    $rows[] = $row;
}

$aDataTableDetailHTML = [];
foreach ( $rows[0] as $col => $value )  {
    $aDataTableDetailHTML[] = array_column($rows, $col);
}
echo json_encode($aDataTableDetailHTML);
```

Which with the test data gives...

```
[["header","content","test"],["header","content","test"],["header","content","test"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added some extra code, it will chunk the `$aDataTableDetailHTML` array into the two values, and then add the key, in this case "header"

```
//There are two elements that are not "header"
$aDataTableDetailHTML = array_chunk($aTempData, 2);

//For every item in the array
foreach($aDataTableDetailHTML as $key=>$tag){
    //Dynamically get the name, in this case, "header"
    $tagName = array_keys( $tag[0] )[0];

    //Start an array containing the tagname ("header")
    $tagOut = array( $tagName );

    //Add the two values onto the array
    $tagOut[] = $tag[0][$tagName][0];
    $tagOut[] = $tag[1][$tagName][0];

    //Drop the keys from the array
    $aDataTableDetailHTML[$key] = array_values( $tagOut );
}

echo json_encode($aDataTableDetailHTML);
```

This gave me the output:

```
[ [ "header", "content", "test" ], [ "header", "content", "test" ], [ "header", "content", "test" ] ]
```

Which seems to match what you were after. Hope that this helps.

I also tested some additional values, and the pattern continued to carry.

Comment: This does not work with simpler tables. Example:
1 2 3 - header
1 2 3 - body

Answer (score 0):

I know this answere comes late, but I have developed a package for this purpose. It is called [TableDude](https://github.com/csskevin/TableDude).

For your case this PHP snippet will work.

```php
// Including TableDude
require __DIR__ . "/../src/autoload.php";

$html = "<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>header</td>
        <td>header</td>
    <td>header</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>test</td>
<td>test</td>
<td>test</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>";

// Parses the HTML to array table
$simpleParser = new \TableDude\Parser\SimpleParser($html);
$parsedTables = $simpleParser->parseHTMLTables();

if(count($parsedTables) > 0)
{
    $firstTable = $parsedTables[0];
    $tableOrderedByColumn = \TableDude\Tools\ArrayTool::swapArray($firstTable);
    print_r($tableOrderedByColumn);
}

// This would output
/*
array(
   array("header", "content", "test"),
   array("header", "content", "test"),
   array("header", "content", "test")
)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

To maintain the parent child relationships between rows and cells, access `td` tags within the context of `tr` tags.

Transposing data structures is done by swapping the first level keys with the second level keys.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Hg45i))

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$result = [];
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $i => $row) {
    foreach ($row->getElementsByTagName('td') as $c => $cell) {
        $result[$c][$i] = $cell->nodeValue;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```