# Convert 2-column HTML table contents to 2d array

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-parsing, domdocument

I am trying to parse the cell values of an HTML table to an indexed array of associative arrays with predetermined keys using PHP.

```
$htmlContent = '<table>
  <tr>
    <th>test1</th>
    <td>test1-1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>test2</th>
    <td>test2-2</td>
  </tr>
</table>';
```

I'd like this result:

```
[
    ['name' => "test1", 'value' => "test1-1"],
    ['name' => "test2", 'value' => "test2-2"],
]
```

My current result is only:

```
[
    ['test1' => 'test1-1', 'test2' => 'test2-2']
];
```

Here my coding attempt:

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML($htmlContent);

$Header = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('th');
$Detail = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('td');

//#Get header name of the table
foreach($Header as $NodeHeader) 
{
    $aDataTableHeaderHTML[] = trim($NodeHeader->textContent);
}
//print_r($aDataTableHeaderHTML); die();

//#Get row data/detail table without header name as key
$i = 0;
$j = 0;
foreach($Detail as $sNodeDetail) 
{
    $aDataTableDetailHTML[$j][] = trim($sNodeDetail->textContent);
    $i = $i + 1;
    $j = $i % count($aDataTableHeaderHTML) == 0 ? $j + 1 : $j;
}
//print_r($aDataTableDetailHTML); die();

//#Get row data/detail table with header name as key and outer array index as row number
for($i = 0; $i < count($aDataTableDetailHTML); $i++)
{
    for($j = 0; $j < count($aDataTableHeaderHTML); $j++)
    {
        $aTempData[$i][$aDataTableHeaderHTML[$j]] = $aDataTableDetailHTML[$i][$j];
    }
}
$aDataTableDetailHTML = $aTempData;
unset($aTempData);
print_r($aDataTableDetailHTML);
die();
```

Comment: Yes it's possible, you'll need to iterate through the table rows and cells and organize the data into an array with the 'name' and 'value' keys.

Comment: thank you. can you please give me an example code

Comment: What have you tried so far? Since there is no example code for this instead it would directly result in an answer

Comment: I Cant add the code here. I don't know the reason but here is the code https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1074174/Simple-Way-to-Convert-HTML-Table-Data-into-PHP-Arr

Comment: Okay so that's one solution you already have and referring to, what's the issue you are facing?

Comment: the output not like I want it. is there any simple way

Comment: So firstly it's difficult to go over a reference site full of a mini project code. Remember that Stackoverflow is not a free coding service. Please share what you have tried to solve the issue, a minimal example can be usefull, and/or a specific error of the code. and also when you post code here it should be concise and explanatory

Comment: find please my code I used in my question

Comment: i believe @Zak has answered your question in update, that solution show work.

Comment: Related: [HTML table to php array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8449116/2943403) and [HTML table to array convert in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46600377/2943403) and [Convert HTML Table to Column Array PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53176670/2943403) and [Parse html table using file_get_contents to php array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8287152/2943403) and [How to parse HTML table using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8816194/2943403)

Comment: @Anna please complete the [mcve] by explicitly stating the exact desired result from your sample HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working too hard to try to keep the columnar data with the respective row.

To make things easier, iterate the row (`<tr>`) elements, then access the elements within the given row.

Code ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/WaYvK)) or ([Alternative Demo](https://3v4l.org/GhoVO))

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$result = [];
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $row) {
    $result[] = [
        'name' => $row->getElementsByTagName('th')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'value' => $row->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    ];
}
var_export($result);
```

Answer (score -1):

I'll do this just because it was fun using `explode` and `str_replace` -- doing it without a PHP DOM parser ..

Basically create a starting Main empty array using `explode( '</tr>', $table );`, and loop through it, add the temp arrays to it after stripping unwanted content (IE `<tr>` and `trimming`)

```
<?php

$table = <<<HTML
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name One</td>
    <td>Value One</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>Name Two</td>
    <td>Value Two</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>Name Three</td>
    <td>Value Three</td>
  </tr>
</table>
HTML;

$rows = explode( '</tr>', $table );
array_shift($rows);
array_pop($rows);

$main_arr = [];

foreach ($rows as $row){
  $name = trim( str_replace(['<td>', '<tr>'], '', explode('</td>', $row)[0] ) );
  $value = trim( str_replace(['<td>', '<tr>'], '', explode('</td>', $row)[1] ) );

  $tmp_arr = [];
  $tmp_arr['name'] = $name;
  $tmp_arr['value'] = $value;

  $main_arr[] = $tmp_arr;

}

print_r($main_arr);
```

Your output should be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Name One
            [value] => Value One
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Name Two
            [value] => Value Two
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Name Three
            [value] => Value Three
        )

)
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the PHP DOM code that does the same thing:

```
<?php

$DOM = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML("<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name One</td>
    <td>Value One</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>Name Two</td>
    <td>Value Two</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>Name Three</td>
    <td>Value Three</td>
  </tr>
</table>");
$main_arr = [];
$rows = $DOM->getElementsByTagName("tr");
for ($i = 0; $i < $rows->length; $i++) {
    $cols = $rows->item($i)->getElementsbyTagName("td");
    $tmp_arr = [];
    if ($cols->item(0)->nodeValue){
      $tmp_arr['name'] = $cols->item(0)->nodeValue;
      $tmp_arr['value'] = $cols->item(1)->nodeValue;
      $main_arr[] = $tmp_arr;
    }
}

print_r( $main_arr );
```

Comment: thank you sir. can I do it using  PHP DOM?

Comment: I added the PHP DOM way of doing it ..   You should edit your question to specify :)

Comment: can you please help me to get it work for this table  `<tr><th class="col label" scope="row">test1</th><td ">test1-1</td></tr>`

Comment: i think we need to do `$Header = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('th');`  but how to add it to your code

Comment: @Zak: regarding a [recent comment of yours on a different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76716823/using-react-hook-to-change-the-value-of-an-input-after-regex-clean-up/76728103#comment135278129_76728103), yes, it was an AI generated answer, one where the spam-link was added days later in an edit.